# Ensure that called scripts exist and are executable with make

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that call a bunch of makers such as compilers and small scripts. Sometime (often a ClearCase issue), the executable flag is missing or worse the script is missing.

What is the best way to check the executable flag and the existence of a list of programs in a Makefile.

My first implementation was to `foreach` on each executable and call them, then catch the exit flag. Because that check takes some time, I had to `ifdef` it in order to bypass the check for all makes rules that does not need to use these scripts. For example the case of `make clean` only call `rm` which has to be installed on all platforms. I don't need to check the other programs.

The second implementation was just to check the execution flag with a `$(shell)` and a `[ -x foo ]` combined in a `ifdef` directive. I feed this solution is a bit ugly.

The third solution is to call a shell script that do the job. However, this shell script must remain executable in any case. I can do `FOO != chmod u+x checker` but this is also quite ugly.

What would be the best solution?

Comment: Is 'ClearCase issue' a shorthand for 'incorrect permissions on file checked into ClearCase'?

Comment: You can use a command line such as `$(SHELL) $(CHECKER_SCRIPT) $(SCRIPTS_TO_BE_CHECKED)` which only requires that the checker script exists and is readable (it doesn't have to be executable).  But you want the compilation to fail if it isn't available and readable, so it isn't a problem if the build fails because the checker script isn't available.  I'm not clear what you're going to do if one of the executables isn't available, unless you build with the `-k` option and it wastes too much effort if nothing is working.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler not sure about ClearCase. I never had this problem myself and the less I have to deal with ClearCase the best I feel. Good idea to instantiate `sh` instead of having `+x` on the script itself. Concerning your remark it is possible I felt into a X-Y problem. Considering this Makefile: `echo -e "foo=$(shell i_dont_exist)\nall:\n\techo$(foo)" > Makefile && make all` make does not fail.

Comment: I don't use the `$(shell ...)` function because I don't write exclusively for GNU `make`. I'm not sure exactly what the error handling semantics are. Roughly what I was thinking of, using your mechanism and no user-defined macros, was: `echo -e "all: scripts programs\nscripts:\n\t${SHELL} checker.sh non-existent\nprograms: prog1\n" > junk.mk && make -f junk.mk` which would do the script checking (`sh checker.sh non-existent`) and if that failed (exited with a non-zero status), the whole build would fail promptly (unless you used `make -k`, in which case parts of the build would fail slowly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will an approach like the following help?

```
target: source ./script_1
    test -x ./script_1 || chmod +x ./script_1
    ./script_1 < source > target
```